# Detect browser DOM changes complete

Tags: javascript, dom, resize

I have a JavaScript code that adds new XHTML to already existing page (DOM tree).
My page elements are dynamic, so adding new elements causes changes in other elements size. I have a custom scroll bar implementation that depends on those sizes and needs to be reset every time they change.

I call the reset method shortly after the statement that inserts the new XHTML. But it seems that this is too soon. Sometimes the scrollbar does not adjust properly. If I add some delay before reset, it is OK, but I consider it too crude and unreliable solution.

I need to either:

Detect when given DOM element completes change of size

or

Detect when the entire DOM change finishes along with the re-layout.

So far I could not find nothing. I know the situation is too complex for most people, but I hope somebody will be able to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about some polling where you check the state of the dom? This is with jQuery and will call `resetMyScrollbar` whenever the html in the page body updates with a maximum half second delay.

```
var lastDom = "";
function checkDomHash() {
  var newDom = $("body").html();
  if (newDom != lastDom) {
    resetMyScrollbar();
  }
  window.setTimeout(checkDomHash, 500);
}
```

In real life I'd use a hash function and compare hashes as comparing huge strings is wasteful.

```
var lastDomHash = "";
...
  var newDomHash = md5OrWhatever($("body").html());
  ...
```

**Edit**

Or you could check the height of whatever the scroll bar is for.

```
var lastHeight = 0;
...
  var newHeight = $("#my_element_id").outerHeight();
  ...
```

Comment: I think in this way I will be only comparing DOM content and will know when it changes, and that is before the re-layout completes. I already tried DOMNodeInserted that serves the same purpose, it does not help :(

Comment: But you have some point, I think about some detection when the target scroll element height actually changes, because that is what I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try the onload event.